# how to read from table in dask in python

Tags: python, dask

I used to have this code to create the dataframe

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DELL;'
                      'Database=DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df_features = pd.read_sql("SELECT ID, filename, code, frequency from Features" , conn)

features_df = df_features.pivot(index='filename', columns='code', values='frequency')
```

I have problem with pivot as dataset is too big 140 million and around 50,000 columns after pivot

people suggested to use dask library

so I built this code a

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=DELL;'
                      'Database=DB;'
                      'Trusted_Connection=yes;')

df_features = dd.read_sql_table(table="Features" , index_col="ID")
```

but this does not work, there is no mention to the connection in read_sql_table function.!

how can I build dataframe using dask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dask.dataframe.read_sql_table function accepts an `engine_kwargs` keyword and `kwargs` keyword, both of which may be helpful for you.  I'm copying them here from the docstring for convenience:

```
engine_kwargs : dict or None
    Specific db engine parameters for sqlalchemy
kwargs : dict
    Additional parameters to pass to `pd.read_sql()`
```

https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe-api.html#dask.dataframe.read_sql_table